# running jupyter-notebook from terminal calls wrong script

Tags: path, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to open jupyter-notebook (Anaconda 3 distribution) from the terminal, but whether I call `jupyter`, `jupyter-notebook`, or `jupyter notebook`, I get an error indicating that what was actually called was `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py`.

I have `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts` and `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3` added to `PATH`, so I can see that it is looking in the right directory, but matches with the wrong file.

Is the solution to add only the .exe's I want to `PATH`, rather than the folder? Or is there a way to add a folder to path such that only .exe's will be noticed.  Or perhaps there is some way of setting the priority when the given command matches multiple entries in `PATH`?

#### Edit:

I got what I need working by reinstalling Anaconda with the 'add to PATH' option selected.  However, I am still interested in *WHY* this issue was occurring, and posting an answer to that may be helpful for future viewers of this page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `jupyter` from the Anaconda Prompt?

On Windows it's bad practice to add the variables to PATH manually to use Anaconda. You lose the entire point of Anaconda managing these things itself.

If all you want is to launch an jupyter notebook using your anaconda distribution just open the anaconda prompt (comes with the installation), make sure the jupyter package is installed and run `jupyter notebook`.

If that doesn't work, might be that the conda environment's path got messed up during jupyter's installation so `pip uninstall jupyter` then `pip install jupyter` from within the Anaconda Prompt.

Lastly, if you haven't already, think about using [conda envionments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) so that you really will never have to mess with your PATH anymore.

Comment: I know it's not hard to open jupyter from the anaconda prompt - however, I like to use git bash, and often have a terminal open within my code editor (usually vs code), so I want the convenience of running python, jupyter, conda, etc. without the anaconda prompt.  Without adding to path I'm not sure I can run those tools from bash or an integrated terminal.  If you know a way to allow that, that would be helpful.

Comment: Also, you're answer doesn't really tell me how to do what I'm trying to, it mostly just tells me why I shouldn't be trying.

Comment: I am interested in what you have to say, however.  Are you saying that adding Anaconda to PATH prevents Anaconda from performing environment management? Why would that be?

Comment: I'm sorry it's not a true answer, I was going to comment but don't have enough reputation points.

On your choice of terminal, I'm not sure there's anything that you can do from the git bash that you can't from the Ananconda Prompt (except for the syntax highlighting).

If you're using VSCode however, I think you can achieve something similar by doing the following:
* Open Anaconda Prompt
* cd to your project
( * activate your environment that has jupyter)
* From the command panel, create a new terminal
* make sure your terminal is in the right env
* run `jupyter notebook`

Comment: Forgot to mention, you have to launch VSCode from the Anaconda Prompt with the activated conda environment for this to work with the command `code`. The result is that your intergrated terminal will work as an Anaconda Prompt, so you get the jupyter/python capabilities as well as git, but you can still use VSCode's git extension.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by reinstalling Anaconda with 'Add to PATH' selected, rather than adding to path manually.